# Undo mysql_real_escape_string

Tags: mysql, line-breaks

I have the following code at the top of every of my php pages:

```
<?php

    function name_format($str)
    {
        return trim(mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_QUOTES)));
    }
?>

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if (!is_array($value))
        {
            $_POST[$key] = name_format($value);
        }
    }
```

This was pretty useful until now. I experienced that if I want to display a text from a `<textarea>` before writing it into a database, then it shows "\r\n" instead of normal line breaks.
Even if I try to do the following, it doesn't work:

```
$str = str_replace("\r\n", "<br>", $str);
```

Comment: Wouldn't *not doing it in the first place* be better than doing and undoing it? :) `mysql_real_escape_string()` should really be used only for the purpose of escaping data before making a query

Comment: Why are you *assigning* to `$_POST`? That's a really strange thing to do.

Comment: Use `mysql_real_escape_string` (or even better [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)) to sanitize a string for input. `htmlspecialchars` alone should be sufficient to sanitize a string _for output_.

Comment: An option would be to use PDO or mysqli, then you  won't have to escape strings at all. Mysql_* functions are also deprecated.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld That is somewhat misleading. What you mean is "always use parameterised queries". It is still possible (and sometimes desirable) to use arbitrary dynamic strings with both libraries. Nor does parameterising queries mean you shouldn't think about other kinds of escaping, such as for HTML or URL parameters. It is always important to consider what escaping is appropriate for a particular context, as I've tried to explain in my answer.

Comment: @IMSoP - yes you're correct that it might have been misleading. Thanks for clarifying! :-)

Answer (score 0):

The mistake you're making here is over-writing `$_POST` with a version of the string which you are hoping will be appropriate for *all* contexts (using `mysqli_real_escape_string` and `htmlspecialchars` at the same time).

You should leave the original value untouched, and **escape it where it is used, using the appropriate function for that context**. (This is one reason why the "magic quotes" feature of early versions of PHP are universally acknowledged to have been a bad idea.)

So in your database code, you would prepare a variable for use with SQL (specifically, MySQL):

```
$comment = mysqli_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['comment']));
```

And in your template, you would prepare a variable for use with HTML:

```
$comment = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['comment']));
```

Possibly adding a call to [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/nl2br) in the HTML context, as desired.